# Select element placeholder in older browsers

Tags: javascript

In short, my question is can I use the `.placeholder` in older browsers that do not support placeholders. For example, assuming `input` is an input element, the following would get the placeholder attribute value.

```
var placeholder = input.placeholder;
```

Does this just read the attribute? If so it would work in a similar way to:

```
input.getAttribute('placeholder');
```

Is there any difference? Will the first one not work in older browsers?

Comment: Perhaps pull up an older browser and find out? ;)

Comment: No access to windows!

Comment: I really just want to know if those two code examples are the same? Because I'm pretty sure javascript in IE8 can still read the attribute value with `getAttribute()` so if that's the case, `.placeholder` seems more tidy.

Comment: **No**, they are not the same, the first one accesses the property, the last one accesses the attribute, there's a difference.

Comment: And yes, you can attach an attribute or property to an element, it will still be there, it just won't show a native placeholder if the placeholder attribute isn't supported.

Comment: And you'd generally create a polyfill setting the value of the input, and the color to slightly faded, then a little trickery to remove the default value on focus, and put it back on blur etc.

Comment: Thanks, yeh I've already nailed the value, blur and focus. Just wondering about the best way to select the elements in the first place.